# How to make Jedi-vim navigate to declaration on Ctrl+click?

Tags: python, vim, pycharm, jedi-vim

I'm trying to setup Vim with [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) for Python development. I would like jedi-vim to navigate to declaration on Ctrl+click (like in Pycharm) instead of the default `<leader>d`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (not tested):

```
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<C-LeftMouse>"
```

in your `.vimrc` before you load the plugin. Than `<leader>d` does not work anymore.

Note: gVim only, does not work in the terminal!

Comment: The problem with this is that for this to happen you would need to move the cursor to the mouses position first. Otherwise it could work.